# VUE- How do I put the values inside of components imported?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, data-visualization

I remember I have seen once how to put the values in the html text area after importing components in VUE.

I'm not sure there is a way to do that or I just remember things in a wrong way.

my code is as below.

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <Heading></Heading>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                <ul class="list-group">
                    <comp v-for='(value,index) in listing' :key='index'>{{value}}</comp>
                </ul>

            </div>
            <serverstat></serverstat>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="row">
            <footing></footing>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import Heading from './assets/Heading.vue';
import comp from './assets/comp.vue';
import serverstat from './assets/serverstatus.vue';
import footing from'./assets/footing.vue';

export default {
data() {
    return {
        listing: ['max','toms','judy','michael','dumdum']
    }
},

    components: {
        Heading,comp,serverstat,footing
    },
};
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

-comp-

```
<template>
   <li class="list-group-item">
    </li>
</template>

<script>
export default {

}
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

After I render this, 
it doesn't show {{value}}. It only shows blank .

How do I insert the {{value}} within the html element?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Using props? https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html

Comment: @CharukaHS I think there was a quicker way to put the value instead of passing the data to the component. Maybe I'm wrong... Thank you though.

Comment: @BS100, If you don't want to use props, you can make use of slots. Also, can you show what listing look like?
https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html

Comment: Well.. quicker, that I can't really confirm, but I peronally like the slot approach (a bit of a synonym to content projection in angular and web component slots. See https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Slot-Content

Comment: @user3791775 I just editted my posting to show the entire code

Comment: @Himanshu I just editted my posting!

Comment: I notice Himansh and I both pointed you to the slots approach... happy reading!

Comment: @user3791775 Thank you so much! I will have a look now. Really appreciate always

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are entering a value *inside* of a component, you can **render** it by using a **slot in your component** like this:

```html
<template>
   <li class="list-group-item">
       <slot />
    </li>
</template>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Yes this is where I finally landed on.

Answer (score 1):

When you use v-for it calls all the value from an array and `:key='index'` defines each object row from an array. If your object listing consists of firstname, lastname as your object then the value you want to print will be {{value.firstname}}. You are missing object name in value.

Can you try this once :

```
<comp v-for='(value,index) in listing' :key='index'>{{value.index}}</comp>
```

Comment: @BS100 is looping a custom (comp) component not some regular element

Comment: @sandesh phuyal so 'value' that I wrote within v-for='(value,index) in listing'
doesn't indicate the names that I have within the array?

Answer (score 1):

```
<comp v-for='(value,index) in listing' :key='index'>
   <slot>{{ value }} </slot>
</comp>
```

Then in comp component use slot as

```
<slot/>
```

Not including the approach for props as you don't want to use that. Use the link above to learn more about slots.

Comment: Thank you so much! yes 'slot' is what I was trying to remember!! Appreciate!